# How to create a fake binary file for an object in R so as to get its md5 hash?

Tags: r

Suppose I want to process an image file, and then store it on disk using its md5 hash as the file name. A naive approach would include the following steps:

1. store the processed image with an arbitrary name;
2. create a connection to the processed image file in R using `file(file_name, "rb")`;
3. apply a function like `openssl::md5()` to the connection to get the md5 hash;
4. rename the file using the md5 hash.

However, this seems inefficient, since the second and third step require additional disk IO.

I am wondering if there is a way to generate a fake file in memory so that `openssl::md5()` can be directly applied to get the same md5 sum without having to store the file on disk first.

Is this possible? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting my reddit answer:

The hint is the the help page to `openssl::md5`, which states that the input object can be a raw vector. So:

```
msg <- "The quick brown fox"
openssl::md5(charToRaw(msg))
```

> md5 a2:00:4f:37:73:0b:94:45:67:0a:73:8f:a0:fc:9e:e5

compare to:

```
writeBin(charToRaw("The quick brown fox"), 'tmp.dat', useBytes=TRUE)
system('md5 tmp.dat')
```

> MD5 (tmp.dat) = a2004f37730b9445670a738fa0fc9ee5

Gives the same output.

Comment: I believe this approach only works for character vectors right? How about other kinds of objects? I wonder if there is a way to save the object to standard output and then read the output using `file()` and then hash it?

Comment: what kind of data are you talking about then? `intToBits` works the same way as above for integers. You can pipe data in and out of stdout, but I don't suspect you'd see much performance advantage over using an actual file.